# ¿Cómo puedo enlazar estructuras de datos en c?

Tags: c, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo esta estructura de datos

```
struct alumnos
{
    char nombre[30];
    int cedula;
    int telefono;
    char materia[40];
};
```

pero quiero que el campo materia sea otra estructura que a su ves tenga sus propios campos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las estructuras se pueden anidar por valor de la siguiente forma:

```
struct materias
{
  int campo1;
  int campo2;
};

struct alumnos
{
  char nombre[30];
  // ...
  struct materias materia;
};
```

Para acceder a los campos propios de `materia` tienes que hacer algo tal que:

```
struct alumnos alumno;
alumno.materia.campo1 = 10;
```

El problema que tiene de usar el anidamiento por valor es que es complicado mantener varias materias sincronizadas (por ejemplo si varios alumnos comparten la misma materia). En este caso conviene usar punteros:

```
struct alumnos
{
  char nombre[30];
  // ...
  struct materias* materia;
};
```

Ahora se podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct materias materiaComun;

struct alumnos alumno1, alumno2;

alumno1.materia = &materiaComun;
alumno2.materia = &materiaComun;

alumno1.materia->campo1 = 1;
printf("%d\n",alumno2.materia->campo1); // imprime "1"
```

Por supuesto también se puede usar, en este caso, memoria dinámica:

```
struct materias* materiaComun = (struct materias*)malloc(sizeof(struct materias));

struct alumnos alumno1, alumno2;

alumno1.materia = materiaComun;
alumno2.materia = materiaComun;

// ...
```

Comment: Entonces yo podría hacer algo como esto strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre.materia, materia);  para poder registrar en mi nodo que el alumno tiene esa materia ??

Comment: Si `materia` es una estructura no puedes usar `strcpy` porque esa función está pensada para cadenas. Si quieres copiar la estructura de un elemento a otro puedes usar el operador = así `registroNuevo->materia = materia`. Fíjate ademas que `materia` no pertenece a `nombre` sino a `registroNuevo`

Comment: Al yo tener esta estructura  

`struct materias
{
 char nombre[30];
  char profesor[30];
  char tipoDeMateria[20];
  char horasSemanales[10];
 struct actividades *actividad;
 struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
 struct materias *siguiente;
};`

y esta otra

`struct fechasEspeciales
{
 char tipo[30];
  char dia[2];
  char mes[10];
 char horaDeIncio[8];
 char horaDeFin[8];
 struct fechasEspeciales *siguiente;
};`  

puedo hacer esto `registroNuevo->fechas.tipo` para poder guardar esa variable tipo junto con la materia que le corresponde??

Comment: Si `fechas` es de tipo puntero tienes que usar el operador `->` en vez de `.`